# SQL Server : read nested JSON from a table and find the MAX value

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have json string as

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = '{"value": [
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211119",
        "ERDAT": "20211119"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211119",
        "ERDAT": "20211112"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211123",
        "ERDAT": "20211123"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "00000000",
        "ERDAT": "20211119"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "00000000",
        "ERDAT": "20211123"
    }]}'
```

And then when I use `OPENJSON` then (only 1st two rows) :

```
key         value                                 type
 0    {"AEDAT": "20211119", "ERDAT": "20211119"}    5
 1    { "AEDAT": "20211119", "ERDAT": "20211112"}   5
```

I want to `MAX` value of the value column. So in the above example the result should be 20211119.

Based on here[1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a74105233f5d14708ef842728aa869c3) and as suggested by someone, I am getting the error as

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '{"AEDAT": "20211119", "ERDAT": "20211119"}' to data type int.

Any clue on how to achieve the same? I am novice to SQL Server hence asking for help.

Comment: Have a look at `OPENJSON`. Then it's *literally* as simple as using `MAX`.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: hint: cross apply openjson on a JSON column returned from openjson. It's even demoed in the help docs.

Comment: Besides @Iptr your way is not yielding the results.

Comment: @Iptr: I am just giving a sample hence two rows were selected. The message was clear that the above table could not be parsed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON keys are dynamic, and you want the max of *any* key, it's easiest to use `OPENJSON` a second time to unpivot the keys

```sql
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(j2.value AS int))
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value) j2;
```

To get the asssociated key, you can use `TOP` instead

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
  j1.[key] ArrayIndex,
  j2.[key],
  CAST(j2.value AS int) MaxValue
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value) j2
ORDER BY
  MaxValue DESC;
```

Comment: this is great. Lets say I want to get the associated key against which I have the `max()` value. If there is a tie then any of the key will do. Can we do that?

Comment: Yes of course have modified

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It calculates the max value is two steps:

1. For each row.
2. Global single max value across all rows for the entire dataset.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @j NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'{"value": [
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211119",
        "ERDAT": "20211119"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211119",
        "ERDAT": "20211112"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211123",
        "ERDAT": "20211123"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "00000000",
        "ERDAT": "20211119"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "00000000",
        "ERDAT": "20211123"
    }]}';

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
    , (SELECT MAX(val) FROM (VALUES (AEDAT), (ERDAT)) AS v(val)) AS MaxValue
    FROM OPENJSON(@j,'$.value') WITH (
          AEDAT int '$.AEDAT',
          ERDAT int '$.ERDAT'
       )
)
SELECT MAX(rs.MaxValue) AS result
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

```
+----------+
|  result  |
+----------+
| 20211123 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Lets assume I want to pass `AEDAT` and `ERDAT` dynamically and that it may be more than two columns or only one column. How can I handle the same?