# SQL:Finding max value from a nested JSON in SQL Server

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-2019, json-value

This question has a reference in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096594/sql-server-read-nested-json-from-a-table-and-find-the-max-value/70097403#70097403).

I want compute the `MAX()` value of the below JSON. Also the keys in this are not fixed hence as per the above solution they can't be **hardcoded** in the code.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = ''{"value": [
 {
   "AEDAT": "20211119",
   "ERDAT": "20211119"
 },
 {
    "AEDAT": "20211119",
    "ERDAT": "20211112"
 },
 {
   "AEDAT": "20211123",
   "ERDAT": "20211123"
 },
 {
   "AEDAT": "00000000",
   "ERDAT": "20211119"
 },
 {
   "AEDAT": "00000000",
   "ERDAT": "20211123"
  }]}';
```

Also I shall be getting the below string as parameter from some other SP.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName = 'AEDAT,ERDAT' ---I shall be getting this as an output from another SP.
```

With the above, my approach is as follows:

```
DECLARE @col_table TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), ColumnName varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @col_table SELECT value as ColumnName FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ColumnName,','); 
DECLARE @max_val TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), LastUpdatedValue int) 
DECLARE @max_ID int
DECLARE @min_ID int
DECLARE @1st_col varchar(max)
SELECT @max_ID = MAX(ID),@min_ID = MIN(ID) FROM @col_table GROUP BY ColumnName;

WHILE (@min_ID <= @max_ID)
  BEGIN
  SELECT @1st_col =  ColumnName FROM @col_table WHERE ID = @min_ID
  INSERT INTO @max_val (LastUpdatedValue)
  SELECT JSON_VALUE(j.value,'$.' +@1st_col+ '' ) FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.value') AS j
  SET @min_ID = @min_ID + 1
  END
```

Ideally the above approach should have given 10 values (5 each for AEDAT and ERDAT) But this is giving me 5 values.

```
SELECT * FORM @max_val;
 ID  LastUpdatedValue
 1    20211119
 2    20211112
 3    20211123
 4    20211119
 5    20211123
```

I am expecting output as like `UNION ALL` of all keys. Like below

```
 SELECT JSON_VALUE(j.value,'$.AEDAT') FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.value') AS j
 UNION ALL
 SELECT JSON_VALUE(j.value,'$.ERDAT') FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.value') AS j
```

What I am missing out? Please suggest.

Comment: Mine is SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OPENJSON` twice, once to open the array, and again to unpivot the keys. Then simply filter by your table variable

```sql
DECLARE @col_table TABLE (ColumnName varchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @col_table (ColumnName)
SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ColumnName,','); 

SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
  j2.[key],
  j2.value
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value) j2
WHERE CAST(j2.[key] AS varchar(100)) IN (
    SELECT c.ColumnName
    FROM @col_table c
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b7860cd76f684dd54979ef041651ab0)

Comment: Getting an error: `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN2" in the equal to operation`

Comment: Good point, need to set `COLLATE` explicitly. You can do this on the table variable, or you can do this in the comparison in the `WHERE`

Comment: I am not getting the Column names in the final table. Besides I am getting 8 rows, instead of 10 rows. Besides, do we need to set `ColumnName` as `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: You did not ask for the key name, have added. I get 10 rows, see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b7860cd76f684dd54979ef041651ab0 Please give a [mcve]. Setting `ColumnName` as PK is more efficient, and it won't make sense anyway to have a key multiple times